# ASP.NET Core MVC project is not showing as a project in the solution explorer

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with VS 2022 and I am trying to follow a tutorial on ASP.NET Core MVC. I am pretty sure I have all the necessary components installed.

When I go to create an ASP.NET Core MVC web application, VS creates the project, but it doesn't compile and the solution explorer doesn't show my project. If I switch to file view I can see a folder, but it doesn't recognize it as a project. Not sure what to do.

I have uninstalled and re-installed several time and ask Chat GPT as many ways as I could for a solution.

Here is my solution after being created:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GftlV.png)

Here is my solution if I switch to a different view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jameq.png)

Here is my solution if I double click the folder:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tanR.png)

It seems to have all the necessary files, but won't start or recognize as a project within the solution. I tried settings and everything I can think of.

This is what I'm expecting from the tutorial I am trying to follow along with:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkUjD.jpg)

Comment: What happens if you try to add the existing project to the solution that you have created? Will it work or will it report an error?

Comment: It won't even show up in the solution.  I can see the new project if I go to the file location, but it will not show up in the solution explorer view.

Comment: You can right click and pick "Add existing project", even if it doesn't show up. It is on the disk as you've showed.

Comment: Hi @Brian, for your such scenario, find the project in the disk and double click the `.sln` file.